# How to add OAuth feature to DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am currently using **WSO2 DSS** to create **RESTful** APIs to access the databases.

I need DSS to perform OAuth authentication for every incoming request. Is there a way I can do it without using WSO2 API Manager or WSO2 ESB?

If I have to change the source code to implement this feature, which particular library should I be looking into?

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario without using WSO2 API Manager you need use three products of WSO2 SOA Suite (ESB, IS, DSS). In other case you can add the WSO2 DSS as a feature to the WSO2 ESB, and use IS as key manager. Check this links and take your best decision.

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/05/tutorial-hosting-restful-web-services-using-oauth-with-the-wso2-platform-0/

https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-tutorial-adding-wso2-data-services-server-dss-as-a-feature-to-the-wso2-esb

Comment: Thanks @Ernesto. I cannot use ESB either. I'm looking ahead at changing the source code of some component of DSS so that OAuth works. I have edited the question too.